# Python Attribute error: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'AF_APPLETALK'

Tags: python

```
import socket
def get_protnumber(prefix): 
    for a in dir(socket):
        if a.startswith(prefix):
            getattr((socket, a), a)


get_protnumber('AF_')
```

When i run this code it gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'AF_APPLETALK'
```

Can someone please explain what's wrong.
How to use function **getattr** and what it does.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr

Comment: `getattr(object, name[, default]) -> value` so i think `getattr(socket, a, a)` this will work

Answer (score 0):

Docstring:
  getattr(object, name[, default]) -> value

`getattr((socket, a), a)` replace this to `getattr(socket, a, a)`

```
import socket
def get_protnumber(prefix): 
    for a in dir(socket):
        if a.startswith(prefix):
            getattr(socket, a, a)

get_protnumber('AF_')

5
18
8
20
3
31
7
12
19
2
10
4
23
15
26
13
16
6
17
24
11
16
14
22
30
1
0
25
9
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.After doing **getattr(socket, a, a)** it gives me 9.not what you have typed above.Why?

Comment: @Taimoor if i do `print socket.__dict__['AF_APPLETALK']` it give me
`5`. please check what you get.